# Can I skip cutscenes in the Walking Dead?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

I'm playing through The Walking Dead again, as it's multiple choice and I wanted to see where the game would/could take you.

But I have to sit through all of the cutscenes and dialogues. It's driving me insane.

Can you skip them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can skip them by holding down the "X" button on your Xbox controller.

If you bought the game on Steam, then there is no way to skip cutscenes.

Comment: Are you talking about the X button on a controller or X key on a keyboard?

Comment: Cheers, i was after the steam version. But an editor took it out of the tags :) Shame... no idea why they would do that then :/

Answer (score 2):

SKIP CUTSCENES

- download Cheatengine 6.7
- select the game in process window
- select select the speed multiplier in SPEEDHACK option
- APPLY
  finish

if you use hotkeys, than you can fastforward like an old Videotape =D

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to skip cutscenes at all. Not on any of the systems.  The reason (I think) is because it's interactive. There really aren't many pure "cutscenes". Most of them have some talking, but mix in a lot of choices, QTE's, and so forth during the talking scenes. It's really hard to differentiate a "skippable chunk of scene". I do admit, it would be a handy feature though.